# Which number goes in the square with the question mark?

Tags: mathematics, grid-deduction

My friend, who loves puzzles as much as me, gave me this image this afternoon.[image]

My friend game me a hint: ***Skyscraper***, which, as Daniel Mathias pointed out in the comments, is a [type of grid puzzle](http://www.brainbashers.com/skyscrapers.asp).

Comment: He gave me a hint : Skyscraper

Comment: Ah, yes. Check out [Skyscrapers](http://www.brainbashers.com/skyscrapers.asp) on BrainBashers or search Google for 'skyscraper puzzle'

Comment: Thanks a lot^^ I'll look into this tomorrow morning^^

Answer (score 8):

Complete Solution to the skyscraper puzzle:

> \begin{array}{|c|c|}\hline5&4&3&1&2\\\hline1&2&5&4&3\\\hline3&1&2&5&4\\\hline2&5&4&3&1\\\hline4&3&1&2&5\\\hline\end{array}

Comment: How pretty. $(+1)$ :D

Answer (score 3):

The answer, as Daniel Mathias has given you, is

> 4

You do not need to solve the entire puzzle to get there, though.  (Although it is entirely possible to solve the whole thing with the information given.)  I was able to answer your question in 6 steps.

A.)

> The 1 above the top left box makes that box "5".

B.)

> The 4 to the right of the top row means that the rightmost cell must be a 1 or a 2; this is also true for the rightmost cell in the fourth row.

C.)

> The bottom cell in the rightmost column must be 5.  [This places 3 in the second cell down and 4 in the middle cell.]

D.)

> With a 5 in the bottom right cell, the leftmost cell in the fifth row must be 4.

E.)

> With the 4 and 5 used up in the leftmost column, this means that the fourth row, second cell (left) must be 5, and the middle cell must be 4.

F.)

> Looking back at the top row, with 5 on the left, and a 1 or 2 on the right, there are six possible ways for the row to have 4 skyscrapers, looking from the right.  However, the 4 has to be in either the target box, or the one to its right.  Since step E used up the 4 in the center column, the 4 in the top row must belong to the target box.